# mongoose how to perform aggregation on ref fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reference, mongoose, aggregation-framework

How to perform aggregation in mongoose on the fields that are based on ref's of other schema..

eg : below id the schema

```
var StorySchema = new Schema({
    _creator : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }
  , title    : String
  , fans     : [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
});
```

how to perform aggregation with creator and fans

thanks in advance

Comment: If you're referring to the aggregation framework, it is limited to one collection only (by MongoDb).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use `populate` function, document: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

`populate` will help you lookup data base on the ObjectIds and the ref collections:

```
Story
  .findOne({title: 'your title'})
  .populate(['_creator', 'fans'])
  .exec(function (err, doc) {
    console.log(doc);
})
```

Output:

```
{ _id: 52b9768a8a770b383d000003,
  title: 'your title',
  _creator: { name: 'user1', _id: 52b975e13e7f2dec31000001, __v: 0 },
  fans:
   [ { name: 'fan1', _id: 52b975e13e7f2dec31000001, __v: 0 },
     { name: 'fan2', _id: 52b975e13e7f2dec31000002, __v: 0 },
     { name: 'fan3', _id: 52b975e13e7f2dec31000003, __v: 0 }] }
```

*you can remove populate function to see the different on result*

Comment: The question was about aggregation though?

Comment: @WiredPrairie yes, I saw your comment above, I am reading the question again, thanks :)